# How to create smooth and goodlooking slightly text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a text that can be shifted for long title.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style>
    #abc {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    #def {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 2em;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        width: 400px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    var teks = null;

    function geser() {
        var left = 0;

        function frame() {
            left--; // update parameter
            teks.style.left = left + 'px';
            if (left == -200) {
                clearInterval(id);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    runningtext();
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
        var id = setInterval(frame, 40)
    }

    function runningtext() {
        teks = document.getElementById("def");
        teks.style.left = '0px';
        setTimeout(function() {
            geser();
        }, 2000);
    }
    window.onload = runningtext;
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="abc">
        <p id="def">Cihampelas Demin Center</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The script is successfully work with 1 line.

Output :

```
Cihampelas Demin Center
```

Question is :

1. Is there another way to print 1 line without `#def { width:400px; }`?

(When I try `#def { display:inline; }`

Output :

```
Cihampelas
Demin Center
```

)

2. When object's `left = -200px`, I want to reserve in same way, but I have no idea.

Comment: Have you tried `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: please clarify.  Do you want crawling text that is on multiple lines or do you want to make the multi-line text go onto one line?

Comment: you should try doing marquee, a Google search reveals many solutions, e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/xxuxd/

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/507674/niet-the-dark-absol , it work